# Looking to revert/remove remote commits to resolve merge conflicts

Tags: git

New to git.

I was accidentally working on an outdated branch, and pushed 6 commits to a remote development branch. When I submitted a merge request (development > master), I was a few commits behind, so I closed the request.

I'm not sure what the cleanest way of fixing this would be. Could I `git revert` my development commits back, checkout a new branch from master, make my changes again, push back to development, and merge without conflict? Since reverting adds another commit, I didn't know if this would just be piling onto my problem or not.

I don't mind having to make my changes again, I just want to make sure I can get this merged without issue, and have everything current when I'm done. I've looked at other options, like `git reset`, but I'd prefer to not add to the problem if I'm wrong.

Below is the output from `git log --graph --oneline --all`

> - a9024a3 (origin/development, development)
> - e9398de
> - af2889d
> - e8a0fea
> - 8681f8a
> - 84e80a5
> - ccf55a0
> - 81de4ff
> - c2bb35c
> - 9e4dcb2
> - 20d385d
> - a7a86b8 
>     | *   331200a (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'development' into 'master'
>     | |\
>     |/ /
>     | * 645a6f7
>     |/
> - f6b10dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could `git rebase` your local development branch onto the latest integration branch that you want to merge into.  This will replay your commits on top of the latest (make sure you `git fetch` to get the latest first).

However, it would be easier to help if you post an image or example of what your tree looks like.

Comment: I was able to do the following from the `development` branch - `git rebase master` > Fixed the conflicts manually > `git rebase --continue`. It looks as though my commits were then applied on top of the rebase dev branch, and I believe it should be set. If I do a `git push origin development` to send up the changes, I should then be able to submit a merge request without conflict. Am I correct?

Comment: @PassLin3, if you see your commits on top of the latest `development` branch, then you should be able to push without conflicts (to the `development` branch).  That is, assuming nobody else has pushed to the branch between your last fetch and push.  In performing the rebase you resolved merge conflicts locally.

Comment: no one else has pushed anything (which is why I was trying to correct this so quickly :) ). I was able to push to `development` and merge to `master` without conflict, and everything looks good. Thanks a lot for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

From what you write it seems you are trying to avoid merge conflicts. If this is the case my advice is you should learn to deal with them as they are common  when working with CVS. The correct way to do what you ask would be a rebase. revert does not delete commits, but create new "inverse" commits to reset the changes. There are ways to "delete commit" (i.e. resetting) but these are strongly discouraged as you can mess up the repo if someone already pulled them. See

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert